# Algorithm for determining the permutations of a word with a dot between one or more pairs of characters

Tags: c#, algorithm, delphi

i am gonna try explain with giving sample.

source:

```
something
```

variations:

```
s.o.m.e.t.h.i.n.g
so.m.e.t.h.i.n.g
som.e.t.h.i.n.g
som.et.hi.n.g.
.
.
.
```

i need a algorithm to create maximum variatons like above in c# or delphi

anyone have idea?

Comment: Homework, possibly?

Comment: Is that last example just badly spelled or do you want to drop/move letters?

Comment: then look for the Edit button.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication {
    public static class ConsoleApp {
        public static void Main() {
            foreach (var permutation in Permutations("some"))
                Console.WriteLine(permutation);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static IEnumerable<String> Permutations(String value) {
            if (value.Length == 1) {
                yield return value;
            } else {
                var current = value.Substring(0, 1);

                foreach (var permutation in Permutations(value.Substring(1)))
                    yield return current + "." + permutation;

                foreach (var permutation in Permutations(value.Substring(1)))
                    yield return current + permutation;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @aeon: Welcome to StackOverflow. If this answer is what you want, you could consider accepting it (as the one who asked the question, you should have a checkmark or somthing near the up/down vote arrows to mark an answer as the accepted one).

Comment: yield. Like :) ... Although recursion isn't advised with yields... You're blowing up the stack.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer Why would yield blow up the stack? It adds a bit of GC pressure on the heap, but probably the string concatenations and collections are more expensive. Also the recursion depth is just 2*n which pales against the O(2^n) runtime.

Comment: Calling the function Permutations is misleading since it isn't a permutation in the mathematical sense. From a function with that name I'd expect that it returns all re-orderings of the letters in the string you pass in.

Comment: There is no need to recursion for this sample, In fact it's not really a permutation to use recursion, so it's not clear way, you can do all the things by one for loop or via linq simply.

Comment: Ok, "blowing up" the stack was too harsh. But the recursion state is saved while you're yielding and enumeration is still needed. So it's a good practice to avoid recursions when yielding.

Answer (score 1):

There are n+1 points where you can insert a `.`. So you can just count in binary to find all variations.

Each bit in your counter corresponds to an insert position. If the bit is 1 then you insert a `.` if it's 0 you don't.

```
for(int variation=0;variation<(1<<(s.Length+1));variation++)
{
  string variatedWord="";
  for(int position=0;position<length(s)+1)
  {
    if(variation&(1<<position)!=0)
      variatedWord+=".";
    if(position<s.Length)
      variatedWord+=s[positon];
  }
  yield return variatedWord;
}
```

Comment: I believe he needs to find the actual results for the different variations, not only count them.

Comment: n+1 if inserting a . in the beginning/end is allowed. And counting in binary directly yields the variations.

Comment: there are n+1 places to place the dot. in each place the dot can be either there or not there. 2^(n+1)

Comment: I think the last sample is (still) a typo, the first sequence suggests begin and end should not be a dot. But it is badly specified.